# separate_wider_regex with lookahead

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, regex-look-ahead

I have a dataframe with sporting events (with no assumptions about the number of spaces or words) with an optional year, that can be formatted in a few different ways.

`tibble::tibble(event_optional_year = c("World Championships", "Summer Olympics 12", "Olympics 2016", "Olympics 2020/221"))`

How can I use `tidyr::separate_wider_regex` to split `event_optional_year` into two columns `event` and `year`? I want `event` in this case to be stripped of the optional year, and `year` equal to `NA`, `12`, `2016` and `2020/2021`, respectively.

I tried fiddling with positive lookahead in the regex:

```
tibble::tibble(event_optional_year = c("Olympics", "Olympics 12", "Olympics 2016", "Olympics 2020/221")) |> 
    tidyr::separate_wider_regex(
      "event_optional_year",
      c(
        event = ".*(?=(?:\\d.*\\d$)?)",
        year = "\\d.*\\d$"
      ),
      too_few = "align_start"
    )
```

but this gives as result:

```
  event                 year 
  <chr>                 <chr>
1 "World Championships" NA   
2 "Summer Olympics "    12   
3 "Olympics 20"         16   
4 "Olympics 2020/2"     21
```

**Question**: which regex does give me the desired result?

Comment: Since you're not processing the latter part (year) any further in this step, `separate`ing by one or more blanks should be equivalent: `separate(event_optional_year, into = c('event', 'year'), sep = ' +')`, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: In the general case, event can have spaces

Comment: `event = "^.*?(?=(?:\\s*\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?(?:/\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?)?)?$)"` and `year="\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?(?:/\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?)?$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnamed patterns in `separate_wider_regex()` simplify this situation a bit. `event = ".*"` is greedy and matches everything before `"\\s+(?=\\d)"` -- any number of whitespace that is followed by a digit (assuming that *year*-part starts with a digit). This handles spaces in *event* but assumes there are none in *year*.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(event_optional_year = c("World Championships", 
                               "Summer Olympics 12", 
                               "Olympics 2016", 
                               "Olympics 2020/221")) %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(event_optional_year, 
                       c(event = ".*", "\\s+(?=\\d)", year = ".*$") , 
                       too_few = "align_start")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   event               year    
#>   <chr>               <chr>   
#> 1 World Championships <NA>    
#> 2 Summer Olympics     12      
#> 3 Olympics            2016    
#> 4 Olympics            2020/221
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Event can have spaces in the general case

Comment: Edit should cover such cases, though it does assume there is no whitespace in the year.

Comment: how would it be done if year has white spaces, I have one case like "Winter Olympics 2018 on 18-02" and would like `year` to be `2018 on 18-02`

Comment: Would excluding digits from `event` work? If yes,  I'd guess replacing `event = ".*"` with `event = "[^\\d]*"` would be one option.